# Not able to print a HTML Table from an Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, html-table, associative-array

I have an Associative Array in this format: **Output of var_export($result)**

```
Harvest_Result::__set_state(array(
    '_code' => 200, 
    '_data' => Harvest_Project::__set_state(array( 
        '_root' => 'project', 
        '_tasks' => array ( ), 
        '_convert' => true, 
        '_values' => array ( 
            'id' => '10287545', 
            'client-id' => '4861417', 
            'name' => 'ABC', 
            'code' => '', 
            'active' => 'true', 
            'billable' => 'true', 
            'bill-by' => 'Project', 
            'hourly-rate' => '145.0', 
            'budget' => '70.0', 
            'budget-by' => 'project', 
            'notify-when-over-budget' => 'true', 
            'over-budget-notification-percentage' => '80.0', 
            'over-budget-notified-at' => '2016-09-24', 
            'show-budget-to-all' => 'false', 
            'created-at' => '2016-03-15T21:38:40Z', 
            'updated-at' => '2016-05-31T23:19:58Z', 
            'starts-on' => '', 
            'ends-on' => '', 
            'estimate' => '70.0', 
            'estimate-by' => 'project', 
            'hint-earliest-record-at' => '2016-03-16', 
            'hint-latest-record-at' => '2016-08-11', 
            'notes' => '', 
            'cost-budget' => '', 
            'cost-budget-include-expenses' => 'false', 
        ), 
    )
)
```

that I am unable to print in the form of a table.

I tried doing this

```
<?php $project_id=10287545;
$result=$api->getProject($project_id);

$data = $result->get( "data" );
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>Project Name</td>
    <td>Hourly Rate</td>
    <td>Budget</td>
    <td>Currency</td>
    </tr>"; 
        foreach($data as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->name;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'hourly-rate'};?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'budget'};?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'budget-by' };?></td></tr>
        <?php }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

But it results in an empty table, without any content. Kindly notify where I am going wrong.

**Update**

I am not using any PHP Frameworks. This code is for querying Harvest using the Harvest API. Here is a link to the Harvest API Wrapper Library in PHP. [http://mdbitz.com/docs/harvest-api/]. It lists relevant classes and methods.

**Output of var_export($data)**

```
<?php
Harvest_Project::__set_state(array(
    '_root' => 'project',
    '_tasks' => array() ,
    '_convert' => true,
    '_values' => array(
        'id' => '10287545',
        'client-id' => '4861417',
        'name' => 'ABC',
        'code' => '',
        'active' => 'true',
        'billable' => 'true',
        'bill-by' => 'Project',
        'hourly-rate' => '145.0',
        'budget' => '70.0',
        'budget-by' => 'project',
        'notify-when-over-budget' => 'true',
        'over-budget-notification-percentage' => '80.0',
        'over-budget-notified-at' => '2016-09-24',
        'show-budget-to-all' => 'false',
        'created-at' => '2016-03-15T21:38:40Z',
        'updated-at' => '2016-05-31T23:19:58Z',
        'starts-on' => '',
        'ends-on' => '',
        'estimate' => '70.0',
        'estimate-by' => 'project',
        'hint-earliest-record-at' => '2016-03-16',
        'hint-latest-record-at' => '2016-08-11',
        'notes' => '',
        'cost-budget' => '',
        'cost-budget-include-expenses' => 'false',
    ) ,
))
```

This is some code for another function, and I am able to generate a table!

```
<?php
$result = $api->getProjects();
$data = $result->get( "data" );
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>Project Name</td>
    <td>Hourly Rate</td>
    </tr>";
        foreach($data as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->name;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'hourly-rate'};?></td></tr>
        <?php }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I am still not sure why I am not able to create a table for the Initial code.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from `<?php ;}`

Comment: I have made the correction in the code, but still there is not content on the table.

Comment: I see the updated array, but it's not clear what that represents. Is that `$result` or `$data` or `$fruit`?

Comment: $data is supposed to represent the final array which I was to print.

Comment: So if you `var_dump($data);` it matches the array you have printed at the top of this question or is $data empty?

Comment: Yes, var_dump($data) matches the array on top.

Comment: @RyanVincent Here is the link for the Harvest API Wrapper Library in PHP. It lists the relevant classes  http://mdbitz.com/docs/harvest-api/

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't anything to loop on if that it the structure of the data. So you are probably looking for something more like:

```
<?php 

$project_id = 10287545;
$result = $api->getProject($project_id);

$data = $result->get( "data" );

?>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Project Name</td>
        <td>Hourly Rate</td>
        <td>Budget</td>
        <td>Currency</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->_values['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->_values['hourly-rate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->_values['budget']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->_values['budget-by']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried following your code. But only the columns get printed and for some reason there is no content.

Comment: Then there is information that is missing in order to assist you. Show the literal output of `var_dump($data);`; include information about what, if any frameworks you are using; provide the code for the `get()` function, etc.

Comment: @user3402248 if you do `$record = $data->get( "values" ); var_dump( $record );` what is the output?

Comment: It returns NULL

Comment: @user3402248 OK, I updated the code. It is odd that the `Harvest_Project` is not returning anything using the inherited `get()` method. So hopefully the change above will still get your data.

Comment: I am sorry, this doesn't work too. Please see my updated post. I have written some code for another function and I am able to create a table. I am not sure why I am not able to create a table for this.